# jquery get previous input text

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following html:

```
    <div class="active_string">
                <input type="text" class="answer" /><div class="images"><img src="/images/myImage.png" alt="" /></div>
                <a href="" class="check_quest" id="1">Click me</a>
</div>
    <div class="active_string">
                <input type="text" class="answer" /><div class="images"><img src="/images/myImage.png" alt="" /></div>
                <a href="" class="check_quest" id="2">Click me</a>
</div>
```

For every click on check_quest I want to get value of a corresponding input. How can I do it using query. I`ve tried the following:

```
$(this).prev().prev().text()
```

but this one and other combinations of prev text() and val are not showing the text Ive put into that textfield.

Comment: Thanks everybody. The first answer accoring to posting/editing time gave the right answer marked as answer. All right answers were upvoted. Thanks to everybody who answered :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you tried `$(this).prev('input')`?

EDIT:

I mean: `$(this).prevAll('input').val()`.

Comment: It should be prevAll instead of just prev, since prev tag of anchor is div tag.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed :) The most important thing is using val() instead of text() though.

Answer (score 8):

It should work with val().

Here is [`working demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/z7hw8/)

Even it is working with

```
$(this).prevAll("input[type=text]").val()
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
$(this).prevAll("input[type=text]").val()
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ovefu3)

Comment: @Yaroslav: Gah! I typed `prev` when I meant `prevAll`. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I think

```
$(this).parent().find('input').val();
```

would be the best way to go.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".check_quest").click(function() {
    var answer = $(this).prevAll("input").first().val();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nalum/QufrR/) is a working example with two inputs that will show you the different values when you click the links

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="active_string">
    <input type="text" id="answer" />
    <div class="images"><img src="/images/myImage.png" alt="" /></div>
    <a href="" class="check_quest" id="1">Click me</a>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".check_quest").click(function(event)
 {
     event.preventDefault();
     alert ($("#answer").val())
 });
```

Here is a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tVcKS/

Comment: this will not work. You modified the original code. `answer` is a class which can occur more than once.

Comment: jAndy is absolutely right. Othervise I would have done it already :-)

Comment: ok, but you could use unique ids, if you have more than one input on a page